# how to get a live updating graph line

Tags: animation, graph, matplotlib, live

i'm trying to create a program which reads some randomly generated data, the xax and yax lists, as plots them live as it reads it in an animated fashion. Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import time, random

ion()
xax = []
yax = []

axes
for j in range (0,20):
    xax.append(j)
    r = random.randrange(0, 20)
    yax.append(r)
maxx = max(xax)
maxy = max(yax)
print maxx, maxy
axis([0,maxx,0,maxy])
line, = plot(xax[0],yax[0])
draw()
for i in xax:
    print i, yax[i]
    line.set_ydata(yax[i])
    draw()
```

Comment: Ok. So what is the question? Does your code work as expected? If not, why not?

Comment: no line appears on the graph, i am unsure why

Comment: Perhaps that should go in your question then. Anyway, your call to `axes` should be replaced by `axes()`. Also the line `line, = plot(xax[0],yax[0])` plots a point, not a line, which is probably why you don't see anything. Try replacing it with `line, = plot(xax, yax)`.

Comment: Has that solved all your problems? If so, I'll form it into an answer.

Comment: i was wondering how to plot the next point on the line, at the moment the line merely shifts on the y axis

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14849/discussion-between-chris-and-daniel-wigmore)

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem please accept it (big gray check box on the left)

Answer (score 0):

Following the discussion in the comments to the question and in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4787710#4787710), try the following to update a line, extending it for each iteration of a loop. The problem in the original code was that only one point at a time was being draw, so obviously no line was drawn to screen. In the following I extend the x and y data at each iteration of the loop using `numpy.append` (part of `matplotlib.pylab`).

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import time, random

ion()

xax = range(0, 20)
yax = [random.randrange(0, 20) for _ range(0, 20)]

axes()

xlim(xmax=max(xax))
ylim(ymax=max(yax))

line, = plot(xax[0], yax[0])

for i, x in enumerate(xax):
    line.set_ydata(append(line.get_ydata(), yax[i]))
    line.set_xdata(append(line.get_xdata(), x))
    draw()
    time.sleep(1.)
```

Comment: on the xlim,ylim bit where is the other ']' meant to go as i keep on getting 'invalid syntax'?

Comment: sorted it, but i get RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length

Comment: The `[`s were typos. I had forgotten to update the x-coordinates in the loop. It should work now.

Comment: that it does, awsome Chris you have been amazing help, so the line.set_x/ydata(append(.. creates a list in which the next data point is chosen?

Comment: No problem. Basically the append, in this case, takes the list of whatever has already been plotted (`get_x/ydata`) and adds to that list the next element to plot on the line, which we plot with `line.setx/ydata`. So it does not create a list, we get the list from `get_x/ydata` and just add to it. Hope that is clear. If you need more help we can discuss this in the chat room.

Comment: @DanielWigmore If this has answered your question don't forget to mark it as accepted. You should probably do this for your other questions as well. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/181221)